# Induction proof - divisibility by 3

Tags: induction

We want to show whether or not $2^{2n+1}+1$ Is divisible by 3 using induction.

I tried doing this but I'm stuck with $2^{2n+3} + 1= 2^2 \cdot 2^{2n+1} + 1$. I don't know how to show if this is divisible by 3.

Comment: $2^{2n+3} + 1= 2^2 \cdot 2^{2n+1} + 1 = 3\cdot 2^{2n+1} + 2^{2n+1} + 1$ and you are through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=0$ this should be clear. So suppose we know that $2^{2\cdot n + 1}$ is divisible by $3$. Then

\begin{align}
2^{2\cdot (n +1) + 1} &= 2^{2\cdot 1 + 2\cdot n + 1}\\
&= 2^2 \cdot 2^{2\cdot n + 1}
\end{align}
is also divisible by $3$, since the second factor is.